# reduce list of functions with keyword argument on dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, functional-programming, reduce

:)

I want to build a very tiny functional pipeline in my code to reduce a bunch of functions on a single dictionary. Every function does 1 thing, but on different keys, here's a simplified example:

I have this dictionary

```
d = {"me": "gab", "you": "cita"}
```

and suppose a silly function like this:

```
def make_caps(dic, on=None):
    if on is not None:
        to_cap = dic.get(on, None)
    if to_cap is not None:
        dic[on] = to_cap.upper()
    return dic
```

I would like to have this working:

```
def reduce_fns_on_dict(fns, dic):
    from functools import reduce
    return reduce(lambda d, f: f(d), fns, dic)

new_dic = reduce_fns_on_dict(fns=[make_caps(on="me"), make_caps(on="you")], 
                             dic=d)

print(new_dic)
```

on console

```
{'me': 'GAB', 'you': 'CITA'}
```

But when I run the above I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: make_caps() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dic'
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more readable to use a dictionary comprehension to perform this kind of things ? Example: `new_dic = {k:v.upper() for k,v in d.items() if k in ["me","you"]} `

Comment: Yeah I this so - I have tried that too I'll post it here soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make_caps(on="me")` calls the make_caps function.  What you want is a new function which behaves like `make_caps(some_arg, on='me')`.  You can make such a function with [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial).  The line will look something like `fns=[partial(make_caps, on="me")...`.

EDIT: Alternatively, you could [curry](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/curry.html) the function.

Comment: `partial`! True! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer from @FiddleStix, I suggest you to use dictionary comprehension, which I find well-suited in your case:

```
d = {"me": "gab", "you": "cita"}
new_dic = {k:v.upper() for k,v in d.items() if k in ["me","you"]} 
print(new_dic)
# {'me': 'GAB', 'you': 'CITA'}
```

*Note: you can remove `if k in ["me","you"]` if you want to capitalize all the values of the dictionary.*